# Uncaught Error: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of Checkbox in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, checkbox

I'm using `react-group-checkbox` component for multiple selection, and for me it is throwing error. This is for first time I'm using `react-check-box`.

Code:

```
<CheckboxGroup 
    name="storebrands" 
    onClick={this.Brands} 
    value={this.state.storebrands} 
    onChange={this.handleUserInput}
 >                                                
    {this.brands.map(function(brands, brandId) {
        return (
            <Checkbox 
                key={brandId}
                value={brands.brandId}
            >
                {brands.brandName}
            </Checkbox> 
        )
    })}
</CheckboxGroup>
```

Comment: What's the output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML content in React

```
<Checkbox key={brandId}
value={brands.brandId} dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: brands.brandName}}></Checkbox>
```

Comment: still throwing the error.dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: brands.brandName}}> what exactly it does?